# Set title when navigation intent to Waze in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an app which i used a navigation functionality by this code:

```
String uri = "geo:0,0?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude;
                Intent navigateIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(navigateIntent, meetAddress+","+city);
                startActivity(chooser);
```

And when I choose WAZE this is how its looks:

[image: Waze Image Intent]

My questions, how can I replace the "Received location" to the address text in Waze dialog?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution:

`private static final String ALLOWED_URI_CHARS = "@#&=*+-_.,:!?()/~'%";
String url = "waze://?ll=" + latitude+","+longitude+"&navigate=yes";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(Uri.encode(url,ALLOWED_URI_CHARS)));
startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 0):

Title of the location can be set in this way

```
geo:0,0?q=latitude,longitude(Label)
```